# How can I determine if a page is loaded in a Facebook iframe using PHP

Tags: php, facebook

I thought this would be simple, but I can't figure it out or find any relavent search results.

I have a Page Tab on my Facebook Page that loads a page from my server in an iframe. I want the page to only be served if Facebook is requesting it.

I've heard of looking at the User Agent, but that doesn't work. With PHP at least... I think.

If I have to I'll resort to redirecting with JavaScript, but that's just sloppy.

Ideally it would look something like this;

```
<?php
...
if ( ! $is_facebook )
{
    header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
}
?>
```

Comment: The browser is requesting it most likely, not facebook.

Comment: I've since come back to this and realized that there is a `signed_request` like @Floyd said and you can tell if the user likes the page with it. So basically, if there's no `signed_request` then don't serve the page. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

Comment: Also, you won't get a `signed_request` if there is a redirect. The reason I wasn't getting a `signed_request` was because I was redirecting all non secure requests to secure ones. So the non secure URL for the Page Tab was redirected. I actually found the `signed_request` in the headers with a status code of 301.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just check the signed_request parameter as described at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/ . If you don't need much security just checking for its presence should be enough. If you need more certainty you can decode it to verify it really came from Facebook.

Comment: I like the idea, but I'm not getting a `signed_request` and I think it's because it's a Page Tab and not an App. This may be useful for something else though.

Comment: Ah, for some reason I thought you were talking about an app on a Page Tab. If it's not an app, I don't think there is any completely certain way to know your iframe is inside a Facebook page.

Comment: I've since come back to this and realized that there is a `signed_request` and you can tell if the user likes the page with it. So basically, if there's no `signed_request` then don't serve the page. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

Comment: The reason I wasn't getting a `signed_request` was because the page was being redirected.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to check the user agent you want to check for the referrer but its not entirely reliable

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.
```

Comment: I was under the impression that `HTTP_REFERER` would not be set because Facebook was directly requesting the page.

Comment: It turns out that the `src` of the iframe and the `HTTP_REFERER` are the same.